# Как удалить текст с QLineEdit при нажатии кнопки?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Как удалить текст с QLineEdit при нажатии кнопки?

Answer (score 6):

У кнопки есть сигнал [clicked](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked), подключайте его к методу [clear()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#clear) у [QLineEdit.](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html)

Пример:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import QPushButton, QLineEdit, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QApplication


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.line_edit = QLineEdit('Hello World!')
        self.button = QPushButton('Click!')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.line_edit.clear)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.line_edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

        self.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = Window()
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

Answer (score 4):

Класс `QLineEdit` имеет метод [`setText()`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlineedit.html#setText).
Вам просто нужно вызвать этот метод с пустой строкой в обработчике события `clicked` у кнопки. Фрагмент кода:

```
button = QPushButton("Очистить", self)
button.clicked.connect(buttonClicked)
line = QLineEdit(self)
line.setText("ТЕКСТ")

def buttonClicked(self):
    sender = self.sender()

    if sender.text() == 'Очистить':
         line.setText("")
```

Comment: Имхо, вызывать `.setText('')` чтобы очистить текст это дикое шаманство Такое же как такая проверка на `true`: `if len(str(True)) == 4: ...` :)

Comment: @gil9red я думаю вы согласитесь, что решение зависит от задачи.

Comment: Ну, ваш способ тоже имеет право жить, как альтернативный, но если нужно что-то сделать, логичнее использовать для этого специализированный метод :) Я так кодревью проводил одному товарищу по его коду на c#, у него был словарь и тот для проверки ключа у словаря писал `var any = dict.Any(x => x.Key == item.Key)`, а ведь у словаря есть такой простой метод `ContainsKey`... : `var has = dict.ContainsKey(item.Key)`. Соглашусь, что через `Any` тоже работает, но зачем делать сложно, когда можно проще :)

Comment: @gil9red можно. Поэтому мой ответ пометили галочкой, а ваш нет ;-)

Comment: Ага, жизнь несправедливая :D

Answer (score 0):

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{

    this->ui->txtOutput->clear();

}
```

В обработчик нажатия кнопки надо добавить метод `clear()`, а `txtOutput` - это имя объекта, то есть окно, которое мы очищаем.

Comment: Python, PyQt5 ?